# Prometheus scrape from unknown number of (docker-)hosts

Tags: docker, dynamic, load-balancing, prometheus

I have a Docker Swarm with a Prometheus container and 1-n containers for a specific microservice.

The microservice-container can be reached by a url. I suppose the requests to this url is kind of load-balanced (of course...).

Currently I have spawned two microservice-container. Querying the metrics now seems to toggle between the two containers. Example: Number of total requests: 10, 13, 10, 13, 10, 13,...

This is my Prometheus configuration. What do I have to do? I do not want to adjust the Prometheus config each time I kill or start a microservice-container.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'myjobname'
    metrics_path: '/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 15s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['the-service-url:8080']
        labels:
          application: myapplication
```

***UPDATE 1***
I changed my configuration as follows which seems to work. This configuration uses a dns lookup inside of the Docker Swarm and finds all instances running the specified service.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'myjobname'
    metrics_path: '/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 15s
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names: ['tasks.myServiceName']
        type: A
        port: 8080
```

The question here is: Does this configuration recognize that a Docker instance is stopped and another one is started?

***UPDATE 2***
There is a parameter for what I am asking for:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'myjobname'
    metrics_path: '/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 15s
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names: ['tasks.myServiceName']
        type: A
        port: 8080
        # The time after which the provided names are refreshed
        [ refresh_interval: <duration> | default = 30s ]
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Can you reach services directly, perhaps on separate ports? Are you able to use service discovery techniques such as Consul or DNS discovery?

Comment: @TobyJackson: It seems as if you gave the "correct" hint at nearly the same time I found the answer by heavy googling :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is very simple:
There are [multiple, documented ways to scrape](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Cdns_sd_config%3E).
I am using the dns-lookup-way:

```
scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'myjobname'
        metrics_path: '/prometheus'
        scrape_interval: 15s
        dns_sd_configs:
            - names ['tasks.myServiceName']
                type: A
                port: 8080
                refresh_interval: 15s
```